# How to vary colors of NetLogo patches randomly

Tags: colors, netlogo

My patches initiate as green (65), black (0), or random base-colors. Every 5 ticks, I would like the green ones to change to a random base color, the black ones to stay black, and the random-colored ones to EITHER become green (65) or change to another random color (one-of remove 55 base-colors).

Implementing this final function (using a subset of the existing random-colored patches) is what I am struggling with.

I have tried ifelse and just different if statements, specifying ask n-of somenumber patches to turn green with the rest turning a random color. This did not work.

```
to setup-patches  ;;PATCHES
  ask n-of 400 patches [ set pcolor 65]
  ask n-of 600 patches [ set pcolor one-of remove 55 base-colors ]
end
```

......

```
to vary-patches
  if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 5 = 0 [ 
    ask patches [ 
      if pcolor = 65 [
        set pcolor one-of remove 55 base-colors ]
      if pcolor = black [
        set pcolor 0 ]
     if pcolor = one-of remove 65 base-colors [
        set pcolor ............................................. ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're more or less there, it's just the `if pcolor = one-of remove 65 base-colors` that is problematic. Every time that statement is evaluated, `pcolor` is compared to a random `one-of` the list generated by `remove 65 base-colors`- it is not checking to see if the `pcolor` is found within that group. For that you need the `member?` primitive. For example, the slight modification below should be doing what you need:

```
to setup-patches  ;;PATCHES
  ca
  ask n-of 400 patches [ set pcolor 65]
  ask n-of 600 patches [ set pcolor one-of remove 55 base-colors ]
  reset-ticks
end

to vary-patches
  if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 5 = 0 [ 
    ask patches [ 
      if pcolor = 65 [
        set pcolor one-of remove 55 base-colors ]
     if member? pcolor remove 65 base-colors [
        set pcolor one-of base-colors
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

**Edit:**

```
to vary-patches
  if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 5 = 0 [
    ask patches [
      ifelse pcolor = 65 [
        set pcolor one-of remove 55 base-colors 
      ] [
        if member? pcolor remove 65 base-colors [
          ifelse random-float 1 < ( 1 / 3 ) [
            set pcolor one-of base-colors
          ] [
            set pcolor 65
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Luke. I was not aware of the member primitive and your application of it here makes sense. However I still need more green! The idea is that we would be changing setting the member? pcolor base-colors patches to turn EITHER 1. another base-color OR 2. green (65). Hopefully, we could get something like 1/3 or 1/2 of them to turn green... at the end of the day, there needs to be more green than any other color. Make sense?

Comment: @MelonieRichey - You can modify the code after the `if member?` statement as needed- for example, see the edited addition to my answer that uses `random-float` to determine whether a randomly colored patch will turn green or to another of the base-colors.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks so much!